# Adding optional arguments to a discord command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@bot.command()
# async def poll(ctx, message, arg1, arg2):
async def poll(ctx, message, *args):
    if len(args) <= 3:

        emoji = '1️⃣'
        pollem = discord.Embed(title='', description=f'{message}')
        pollem.add_field(name='{1} {0}'.format(args[len(args)], emoji), value=args[len(args)], inline=False)
        pollem.add_field(name='{1} {0}'.format(args[len(args)], emoji), value=args[len(args)], inline=False)
       # pollem.add_field(name='{1} {0}'.format(args[2], emoji), value=args[2], inline=False)
       # pollem.add_field(name='{1} {0}'.format(args[3], emoji), value=args[3], inline=False)
```

So thats my code right now.
the command is `.poll {message} {arg 0} {arg 1} {arg 2} {arg 3} {arg (n)}`
Now I tried to get an optional amout of args, but I dont know how i will get there.
If I try it like `.poll {message} {arg 0} {arg 1}`, I get

```
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

Python indexes start at 0. If you do `args[len(args)]` you are garanteed to get index out of range. If you want to access the last argument you need to do `args[-1]`

Edit:
As said in the comments, you just need to do `args[-1]`

Comment: To access the last index of a python list, it is simpler to call `args[-1]`.  No need to correct for the length.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this?

```
@bot.command()
# async def poll(ctx, message, arg1, arg2):
async def poll(ctx, message, *args):
    if 0 < len(args) <= 3:

        emoji = '1️⃣'
        pollem = discord.Embed(title='', description=f'{message}')
        pollem.add_field(name='{1} {0}'.format(args[len(args) - 1], emoji), value=args[len(args) - 1], inline=False)
        pollem.add_field(name='{1} {0}'.format(args[len(args) - 1], emoji), value=args[len(args) - 1], inline=False)
```

Comment: `.poll "Message" "Arg1" "Arg2"
CommandBot
BOT
heute um 03:57 Uhr
Message
:one: Arg2
Arg2
:one: Arg2
Arg2 `

Thats the Output if i try it with your way. :)

Comment: @SwiftCoding - thank you very much for your feedback. I will work on this now and hopefully get back to you. In the meantime, if you could upvote my post, that would be helpful! :-)

Comment: I just tried to vote your answer up, but i dont have enough rep.

Btw, couldnt figure our any solution yet.

Comment: @SwiftCoding - hey mate, sorry I don't think I can solve this one unfortunately. All good mate, I don't think I deserve an upvote either way :-(

Comment: @SwiftCoding - thank you for letting me know! I will upvote that answer!

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, took some more days. Here is the code.

```
        for x in range(1, len(args), 2):
            context.append(args[x])

        for a in range(0, len(args), 2):
            pollem.add_field(name=' {1} {0}'.format(args[a], reaction[int(r / 2)]), value=context[int(a / 2)],
                             inline=False)

        ms = await ctx.channel.send(embed=pollem)

    else:
        await ctx.channel.send('Check Args')
```

If anyone got any questions, just hmu!

Comment: Please [format](/help/formatting) and indent your answer correctly. Use backticks or tildes for code-fences, not apostrophes. Also, _explain_ your answer instead of just dumping code. From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_

Comment: Sorry, the formattig is sometimes a bit strange on my phone. But fixed it now.

And I prefer not to comment my answer, instead of commenting it not properly.